# How do I change the order of items on resize?

Tags: css

Is there a way to force the third element to always be directly below the first element when the screen size is 500px or less?

```css
.user { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  padding: 4px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #block >div:nth-child(3) {
      display:inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      top:120px;
      left: 120px; /* errorful line as the elements are not sync */
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="user">Element One</div>
  <div class="user">Element two</div>
  <div class="user">Element three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the wrapped `<div>` elements can be changed by assigning `flex` to the `display` style of the `<div>` element whose `id` attribute is `main`. To change the `order` of the items, change the order style of the items within the media query.

```css
#main { 
  /* The following styles have been applied to the outer container. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.user {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#user1 {
  color: red;
}
#user2 {
  color: blue;
}
#user3 {
  color: green;
}

/* I set max-width to 768px to test app on mobile screen size. */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Change the order style to change the order of the items. */
    #user1 {
      order: 1;
    }
    #user2 {
      order: 3;
    }
    #user3 {
      order: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="user1" class="user">One</div>
  <div id="user2" class="user">Two</div>
  <div id="user3" class="user">Three</div>
</div>
```